# export default arrow function cannot be imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React, and I have something like this in my code:

**renderDetails.js:**

```
export default renderDetails = (details) => {
    // function logic removed for brevity
}
```

Then, in the same folder, I have another source file from where I want to import it, and I do something like this:

**businessDetails.js:**

```
import renderDetails from './renderDetails';
// rest removed for brevity
```

But, I get an error message pointing to my `renderDetails.js` file and says: "rederDetails is not defined". Any ideas what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Comment: You can directly write like this `export default (details) => {..}` and import as above would work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that even though you are exporting the component as default you are giving it a name which is not defined

You can either do

```
export default (details) => {

}
```

or

```
const renderDetails = (details) => {

}
export default renderDetails;
```

One more thing, when you are trying to render components, make sure that their name starts with a `Uppercase` character.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Also you need to use Uppercase first character if you want to render a React component

Comment: Nice answer for 'export' but how can I import this nameless function in another file ? @typos

Comment: @Shamim Since it is a default export you can import it with any name like `import renderDetails from '/path/to/render';`

Answer (score 2):

try that way.

`functions.jsx`

```
export function renderDetails(details) => {
    // function logic removed for brevity
}
```

then import like,

```
import { renderDetails } from './functions';
```

P.S.
`./` is for if both files a re in same namespace/folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write them like this:

```
export const exampleFunctionOne = () => {}

export const exampleFunctionTwo = () => {}
```

Then import the individual functions you require from said file like this:

```
import { exampleFunctionOne, exampleFunctionTwo } from './exampleFile';
```

I like this approach when wanting to combine similar functions into one file such as validators or filters making them easy to import and use across your application.